# What does it mean for a constant to be untyped?

Tags: go

The [Go Programming Language Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants) says that:

> Constants may be typed or untyped

I am having a little doubt in my understanding.
Consider this example in the spec:

```
const l = "hi"             // l == "hi"  (untyped string constant)
const m = string(k)        // m == "x"   (type string)
```

The spec says:

> constant may be given a type explicitly by a constant declaration or
>   conversion, or implicitly when used in a variable declaration or an
>   assignment or as an operand in an expression

By this statement, why isn't `l` typed since it is clearly a constant declaration?

This behaviour is clearer with another [example](http://play.golang.org/p/h1ghL-ec-t)

```
type Foo string
func f(a Foo) {}

func main() {
  f("sarkozy")

  const t = "julie gayet"
  f(t)

  s := "hollande"

  //compile error
  // f(s)

  f(Foo(s)) // ok
}
```

Is the reason that `f("sarkozy")` compiles be due to this statement on Assignability in the spec?

> x is an untyped constant representable by a value of type T.

My argument is the following:

- "sarkozy" a an untyped literal.
- Thus "sarkozy" being representable by `Foo` means I can type coerce like this  `Foo("sarkozy")`
- `f(s)` fails because s is not *untyped*.

Comment: I'd recommend anyone interested in this read [The Go Blog: Constants](https://blog.golang.org/constants).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Why isn't l typed since it is clearly a constant declaration?**

Yes, it is clearly a constant declaration, as your quote says:

> constant may be given a type *explicitly* by a constant declaration

However, in your case there is no explicitly given type. You can only have an implicitly given type when *"used in a variable declaration or an assignment or as an operand in an expression"*.

**Is the reason that f("sarkozy") compiles be due to this statement on Assignability in the spec?**

Yes, the reason that `f("sarkozy")` compiles is because the untyped constant of "sarkozy" has a type given implicitly when used as an operand in an expression such as in your case.

"sarkozy" is implicitly given the type of `Foo`

**So why doesn't `f(s)` compile?** (okay, that was not in the question, but the question remains)

Your argument states that: *"f(s) fails because s is not untyped."*

True that `s` is not untyped. s is a variable and not a constant, and variables cannot be untyped.

The Go specs states for [Variable Declarations](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Variable_declarations):

> If the type is absent and the corresponding expression evaluates to an untyped constant, the type of the declared variable is as described in §Assignments.

And that refers, from what I understand to the following:

> the constant is first converted to type bool, rune, int, float64, complex128 or string respectively, depending on whether the value is a boolean, rune, integer, floating-point, complex, or string constant.

So, the following line:

```
s := "hollande"
```

will declare the *variable* (not constant) `s` of type `string` because the right-hand expression is an untyped string constant. The type is implicitly given during the declaration of the variable, not by analyzing what context it which it later on will be used.

f(s) will then result in a compile error because you try to use a value of type `string` where a value of type `Foo` is expected.

Comment: Thanks. This "variables cannot be untyped" was key for my understanding.

Comment: Thanks... nice explanation, i tried to understand more using this code https://go.dev/play/p/err2cySkAXp and the output doesn't help  so much as this article. So if a understand well: There is kind of magic poliformish in the ´const t = "julie gayet" `, so that value can switch to type Foo (beign actually an untyped string constant)... viewing things from  an OOP glasses lets say... right?